# How can I get a simple way of verifying if a button is clicked, and if it is, change it's text?

Tags: c#, button, panel

I have a panel where I have a lot of buttons. Is there a way I can check if any of those buttons are clicked, and if it is, change the text from that specific button?

I've been looking around and I've got till now is this

```
foreach (Control button in panel1.Controls)
{
    if ( button.Click == ??? ) //I can't use '==', 
                                //but I don't know what to do here
    {
        //changing the text would happen here
    }   
}
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: You need to set a click handler for the button and change the text from there, buttons don't have a "clicked" state. Check MSDN for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Bun unless they are toggle buttons, but should still be handled via an OnClick event.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys, I think these answers can help me in what I need. Thanks for the attention! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could let all buttons use the same click-event handler:

```
protected void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Button) sender).Text = "Insert Text Here";
}
```

In your constructor:

```
this.Button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button_Clicked);
this.Button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button_Clicked);
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing you can do is to attach the same event handler to all of your `Buttons` *Click* event inside of your `Panel`.

```
var buttons = panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>();


foreach(var btn in buttons)
      btn.Click +=  Button_Click;

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var btn = sender as Button;
   if(btn != null) btn.Text = "Something else";
}
```

Or you can do it with lambda statement instead of declaring separate method:

```
var buttons = panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>();


foreach(var btn in buttons)
      btn.Click +=  (s,e) => ((Button)s).Text = "Clicked";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm gonna try both answers, that will definitely help :)